# Entity Framework 6 cast inheritance object when doing where clause

Tags: entity-framework

let' say i have a Comment table, 
Admin and Member can Comment on it.
Admin and Member are inheritance from User,
so now i want to get comment and filter by a specific properties of member (groupName)

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; } //member or admin
}
public class Admin : User
{
    public string someProp { get; set; }
}
public class Member : User 
{
    public string groupName { get; set; }
}
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("user")]
    public int user_id { get; set; }

    public virtual User user { get; set; }
}

var comments = db.comments.Where(c => c.user.type == "member" && c.user.groupName == "abc").ToList();
```

of course above code can't working,
so any idea for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var comments = db.comments.Where(c =>
    c.user is Member &&
    (c.user as Member).groupName == "abc"
);
```

Also, if you'll expose the other end of the association (User -> Comments), it could be much easier:

```
public abstract class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; } //member or admin

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var comments = db.users
                 .OfType<Member>()
                 .Where(x => x.groupName == "abc")
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Comments);
```

P.S I took the liberty to mark your `User` class as `abstract`.

Comment: thanks a lot ! It Work
i m using Web API 2 & OData v4 too.Here i share a question and answer for this "Extend" problem i face.
the request url for odata will be localhost:6663/api/comments?$filter=user/EFDB.Member/groupName eq 'groupA'" for about code. 
Not use isof().
refer: http://www.wenda.io/questions/5079367/using-odata-function-isof-with-web-api.html

Comment: Keep in mind that `user.type` is redundant when you're already checking the type using `is Member` or `OfType<Member>()`.